# How to pass docker volume name to docker compose.yml

Tags: docker

I know needed volume name

```
sudo docker volume ls
...
cfc151dc475be39535b438d54d245107c5f1ce022622a0eae53bc03016aa987d
```

And I want to pass this volume (but changing in command line) to docker compose file.

```
nginx:
  image: "nginx:alpine"
  ports:
    - 6000:80
  links:
    - registry:registry
  volumes:
    - ./auth:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./auth/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    - ./auth/domain.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt:ro
    - ./auth/domain.key:/etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key:ro

registry:
  image: 5money:latest
    volumes:
    - registry-external-data:/var/lib/registry

volumes:
  registry-external-data:
    external: true
    ??name: $data??
```

I don't understand last line, what is correct? I want start compose something like this:

```
sudo docker-compose -f 5money-compose.yml up -d -e data=cfc151dc475be39535b438d54d245107c5f1ce022622a0eae53bc03016aa987d
```

Comment: Why do you want your volume name to be a string of random characters? Why not choose a sensible name instead?

Comment: @ArturMeinild, this volume was created automatically, my first start composer has been without volume definition at all. Now I want reuse existing volume. And is string name (sensible or random) critical to correct build composer file? Name is only string litheral, but how to correct define it in compose file?